# Magento database tables - where is EAN stored

Tags: magento

I am working on a Magento project and to complete an import to ebay process I may need to do a bulk update on EAN numbers.

I am reviewing the database and the tables - and I haven't found or see any indication as to where this "EAN" field is stored.

I can see it present on individual products under "general" in the edit panel on the magento site

Answer (score 1):

Read about EAV.

**get eans with product ids**

```
SELECT entity_id, value FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar 
WHERE attribute_id IN ( SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'ean');
```

**write ean to magento**

```
INSERT INTO catalog_product_entity_varchar
(value, entity_id, entity_type_id, attribute_id, store_id)
VALUES ('".$value."', ".$productId.", 4, ".$attributeId.", ".$storeId.")
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = '".$value."'
```

where $attributeId is the id of "ean" attribute from table eav_attribute

Comment: well the table is labeled as mage_  --- SELECT entity_id, value FROM mage_catalog_product_entity_varchar 
WHERE attribute_id IN ( SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'ean'); -- but this creates the following error  [Err] 1146 - Table 'eav_attribute' doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

As it is present under "General" tab when viewing individual products, it means that EAN is a product attribute.

Values are stored in `catalog_product_entity_*` tables, based on the backend type of the EAN product attribute. In case you don't know the type, you will need to check the contents of `eav_attribute` table for the EAN record.

A good article that explains Magento's database structure can be found here: https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/eav-database-structure/

Comment: I've not seen the EAN records though - do you have a screenshot of the table - with this data in question

Answer (score 0):

I dont think Magento comes with EAN code out of the box. You have to create an attribute for that.

Comment: yeah I think we had to do that in the end